# Inconsistencies between iPod and iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, ipod

I have an iPod with 100G of music. Then I open iTunes on my Mac, and I can use coverflow for some music files that are on the Mac, where the iTunes library resides. But I can not see coverflow from iTunes, when I click on my iPod, and I have covers for almost all of the albums.

How can I use coverflow on iTunes on the Mac but browsing songs that are on my (connected) iPod

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be possible, certainly it's not available on iTunes 9.2.x on Windows 7/XP, though I'm still unsure why. I'd hazard a guess that it's something to with the iPod having to communicate via USB, which would probably slow things down uncomfortably. But this is, of course, simply a guess.

For what it's worth Apple does offer the option of submitting an 'enhancement request':

1. http://www.apple.com/feedback,
2. Select the relevant area (iTunes, under 'Software'),
3. Enter the relevant details, selcting 'enhancement request' under the 'feedback type.'

...I'd suggest a possible fourth step of 'not holding your breath,' but that's perhaps my own pessimism coming to the fore, and isn't intended as a comment on Apple specifically. =/